# jQuery returning array when I want a node

Tags: jquery

Can someone take a look at Line 77 in https://github.com/mayeskennedy/plugins.mayeskennedy.co.uk/blob/master/jquery/stateful-scrolling/stateful-scrolling.jquery.js ??

It's the response from a jQuery AJAX GET request

```
$.get('index.html', function(data) { $(data); });
```

it's returning an array when I want a single jQuery object.

I thought it was because I had badly formed page but it validates at the W3C.

Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: What you have will be a single jQuery object. Your console is just making it look like an `Array`. Try `alert($(data).fn.jquery)` and be suprised.

Comment: A jQuery object is an array (or "pretends" to be) even it only contains one element.  Try `$(data)[0]`.

Comment: @gdoron `data` is a well formed html string

Comment: @Rocket I want to build it up and do `$('#myselector', data)` but it's not working.

Comment: `id` is **unique**, no need to give it context! anyway try it with `$('#selector', $(data)...`

Comment: Okay. If I run `$('body', data)` it returns `[]`. This is not correct as I know data is a valid html page.

Comment: @gdoron I want to find `#selector` within `data` not the current document.

Comment: @Simon: Try `$('#myselector', $(data))`  `data` is an HTML string, to use it as a context, it needs to be a selector, DOM element, or jQuery element.

Comment: @Simon: `$(data).find('#myselector')`?

Comment: @Rocket still doesn't work :-(

Comment: It appears that this only works for snippets of HTML and not the whole page. It essentially ignores `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tags. If you try `$.get('', function(data) { console.log($('body', $(data))); });` on any page it also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery cannot deal with a complete HTML page in that way. Try:

```
$('#selector', data.replace(/(<body[^>]*>)/i, '$1<div>').replace(/(<\/body>)/i, '</div>$1'));
```

And your luck will change.

Answer (score 1):

Every jQuery object looks like an array, this is it was designed.

For example, if you want to get the element from an `id selector`, which return a single- unique element:

```
$('#id')[0].value...
```